# Highlight row cell if value in column a doesn't match in column b in devexpress

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

can somebody help me, how to highlight row cell if value in column a doesn't match in column b in `Devexpress VB.NET`. 
[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7xtP.png)

Comment: please clarify that which you want to hightling row or cell ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Conditional Formatting](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument17691) feature which allows you to change the appearance of individual cells or rows based on specific conditions.

I believe, the [FormatConditionRuleExpression](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsFormatConditionRuleExpressiontopic) will be helpful:

```
Imports DevExpress.XtraEditors
Imports DevExpress.XtraGrid

Dim gridFormatRule As New GridFormatRule()
Dim formatConditionRuleExpression As New FormatConditionRuleExpression()
gridFormatRule.Column = colA
gridFormatRule.ApplyToRow = True
formatConditionRuleExpression.PredefinedName = "Red Fill, Red Text"
formatConditionRuleExpression.Expression = "[A] != [B]"
gridFormatRule.Rule = formatConditionRuleExpression
gridView1.FormatRules.Add(gridFormatRule)
```

Comment: Brilliant very helpful, thank you very much @DmitryG.